# Horizontal scrolling View with varying Column width

Tags: ios, objective-c, scroll

I'm a bit stuck in this and need some guidance. I want a responsive view that can scroll horizontally with cells of varying widths (height is all the same). (I want to build a TV guide application).

I have been able to build this with a hierarchy of views added at runtime to ONE superview but the responsiveness while scrolling horizontally is absolutely lame.

Obviously I have done something wrong from the architectural point of view and am looking for some guidance. (by the way - the view can be zoomed and I have a total of 240 sub views and each has about 5..8 subviews being visible). Looks like this is too much for the iphone in the way I have built this.

I would appreciate very much if somebody can point me in the right direction as I'm a bit lost in the moment.

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: `UICollectionView` ?

Comment: I recommend a UICollectionView, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a collection view with flow layout:

http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-collection-views-using-flow-layout/

Additionally, override the following method to achieve varying widths:

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout *)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```